# Viewwillappear not called after dismissing modalviewwontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

in my `firstviewcontroller` I presented a `modalviewcontroller` , then through an action I call a method that show an alert and dismiss the `modalview`, but when it disappear viewWillAppear is not called :

**firstviewcontroller**

```
-(IBAction)AddActivity:(id)sender{


    CreateActivity *addViewController = [[CreateActivity alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateActivity" bundle:nil];

    addViewController.delegate = self;
    addViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    addViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:addViewController animated:YES];


    addViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 260, 680, 624);

}
//in secondviewcontroller I use an alert view that call this method in order to dismiss modalview

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){


        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]){
            [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        else {
            [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

when It disappear , `viewWillAppear` is not called , what I am missing please

Answer (score 6):

Change below code it will work:

```
 addViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

It will Work.

Comment: It is not a solution. 1)what if I need another presentation style? 2)when the presenting view controller appears background view becomes black and it is bad

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that viewWillAppear is not called when the view disappears. The method you are looking for is viewWillDisappear.

See below for additional explanation.

– viewWillAppear:
Called right before the view will appear.

– viewDidAppear:
Called when the view has appeared(visible on screen).

– viewWillDisappear:
Called right before the view will disappear.

– viewDidDisappear:
Called when the view has disappeared(not visible on screen).

Also make sure your code is written properly like so:

```
- void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // work your magic here
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    // work your magic here
}
```

Comment: thank  you for reply, Even when I add viewwilldisappear, It didn't access to viewwillappear of my firstviewcontroller

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? Also could you please post your viewWillAppear code?

Comment: No I didn't , I just present modaly my viewcontroller ,And want to dismiss it , and then call viewwillappear to do some manipulation

Comment: You are trying to get viewWillAppear called on presenting view controller, yes?

Comment: Don't forget to call [super ...] for each of those.